# Python sklearn: oneclassSVM never converges

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently having an issue training an [`svm.OneClassSVM`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-oneclass-py).

I reduced the issue to a minimum example:

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
X_train = pd.read_csv("occ_data.csv")
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.01, 
                      random_state=42, tol = 0.1)
clf.fit(X_train.as_matrix())
```

Dataset can be obtained [from github.com](https://github.com/BernhardSchlegel/stackoverflow/blob/master/occ_data.csv). Other kernels (e.g. `'rbf'`) do not help.

Any ideas for causes and/ or workarounds are highly appreciated. Thanks.

I'm on Python Python 3.6.0 using Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) distribution.

Comment: what was the silent downvote for ?

Comment: have you tried scaling the data before fitting `OneClassSVM` ?

Comment: Code works for me (maybe 1 sec). But Abhishek's comment is important (not only from the train-time perspective)!

Comment: Bingo ! Scaling helped. I wonder why the error message *UserWarning: Numerical issues were encountered when centering the data and might not be solved. Dataset may contain too large values. You may need to prescale your features.* did not show up.

Comment: @Abhishek Thakur: Thanks for the hint. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it. Would be intereseted WHY an SVM needs a scaled featurespace to converge.

Comment: @Boern done. :) check this out: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154224/when-using-svms-why-do-i-need-to-scale-the-features

Comment: @Boern (For the reason about scaling: ) Check out sklearns user-guide on SVMs. I'm too lazy to look for it right now, but there is a sentence like *SVMs are not scale-invariant*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data must be scaled before SVM:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_train = pd.read_csv("occ_data.csv")
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.01, 
                      random_state=42, tol = 0.1)
scl = StandardScaler()
clf.fit(scl.fit_transform(X_train.as_matrix()))
```